# Linking to pthread or not determines the different behavior of the program

Tags: c++, multithreading

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int main(int nArgCnt, char*ppArgs[]) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<decltype(mtx)> lock(mtx);
    std::condition_variable condVar;
    int x = 0;
    condVar.wait(lock, [&] {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
            return x > 0;
        });
}
```

I build above code with `g++ main.cpp -o test`, the the `test` prints infinite lines:

```
0
0
0
0
...
```

However, if I built with `g++ main.cpp -lpthread -o test`, only one line is printed:

```
0
```

I have tested with different versions of Linux and different versions of g++ compilers, and got the same phenomenon.

Why adding `-lpthread` or not lead to different behavior of the code?

Ps. If I removed the line `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);` , the test always print infinite lines whether `-lpthread` is added or not. So weird...

Comment: You need to link `pthread` when you are using `<thread>`.

Comment: I Know it, but the almost equivalent question is: even pthread is linked, add `std::this_thread::sleep_for(0ms);` or not leads to different behavior.

Comment: if you put the thread to sleep this affects scheduling and this affects spurious wakeups. How often did you expect to get `x` printed? And why? Why do you think it is weird? Btw I dont think that this is the "almost equivalent question". You must link pthread, that you get similar effects from something else does not necessarily imply that their cause is related

Comment: Well, let us always link to pthread and remove the `this_thread::sleep` line. Just add `std::thread t([]{});` before `condVar.wait` or not will leads to different behavior as well. How do you explain? I just want to know why. Thanks.

Comment: why do you actually care? how and why spurious wakeups happen is beyond your reach. It in the hands of your operation system. What operating system are you using?

Comment: not sure, but maybe you need to understand first what a "spurious wakeup" is and why they can happen. Unfortunately I don't have a good reference to refer to

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to learn about "spurious wakeup". I care about the phenomenon because the infinite loop consuming too many CPU time. I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 18/20, with g++ 7/8/9/10)

Comment: typically you wouldnt not have `std::cout << x << std::endl;` in there. I suppose this affects the behavior as well. Typically waiting for a condition variable uses very little cpu

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I'm on GCC-11.3. You might encounter some behavior being compiled out (mutexes turning into no-ops etc) when you compile for single threading. And if so, the compiler can assess that this whole thing turns into an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you tried to link with pthread, but comment or uncomment the line `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);` . Which may produce identical phenomenon.